# How to share project Version number between a Post-deployment and a pre-deployment script in DB project

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

How to share project Version number between a Post-deployment and a pre-deployment script in DB project.

Need to insert a record during pre-deployment and update the same record during post deployment but do not want to specify the version number on  two places as this need to be changed for every release.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Create temporary table meantime  pre-deployment, store value (e.g. ID of inserted record), then get date in post-dep and remove table (?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to have a table for single value. looking for something like  global variable like stuff.

Comment: Do you want to insert one record in pre-dep (?) into table with identity?
Then during post-dep you could take row with biggest ID...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply again.Unfortunately the primary key is Guid on that table.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a one row table holding the version number.

Comment: If you don't want a table you could <terrible-idea> store the version number as an extended property on some unsuspecting database object using [`sp_AddExtendedProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) </terrible-idea>. "If all object types and names are null, the property belongs to the current database itself."

Comment: I just came to know about this. using SQLCMD variable with default value.

Comment: Thanks all finally went with Temp db Thank you all.

Comment: You can use variable for that

Comment: Thanks for the reply.